# How do I work around the "You are missing the recommended JDK" error?

Tags: unity

After switching to 2019.4 LTS I got this error (using Windows 10)

> You are missing the recommended JDK. Install the recommended version using Unity Hub.

[image]

I installed the JDK using Unity Hub many times now, still the same error.

Tho I don't think it's getting installed.

As you can see below, the "OpenJDK" checkbox remains blue no matter how many I try to install it.

[image]

When I tried downloading and installing the JDK (JDK 1.8.0_181) myself I get this error instead:

> You are missing the recommended JDK, versions other than 1.8.0 are not officially supported.

Comment: This looks like a bug to report to the Unity support team.